# Remove DIV only if empty

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a PHP notification system, and the amount of notifications is put into a DIV using jQuery. The only problem is that when there are 0 notifications, the empty DIV still shows up. This is the jQuery I am currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/codes/php/nf.php', function(a) {
        $('#nfbadge').html(a);
        $('#nfbadge:empty').remove();
    })
});
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('http://localhost/codes/php/nf.php', function(a) {
        $('#nfbadge').html(a);
        $('#nfbadge:empty').remove();
    })
}, 8000);
```

The only problem is that if at document load there is 0 notifications and a notification is added, the badge will not show up, so basically if the element is removed it won't come back unless the page is reloaded, but I made the notification system so that the page wouldn't have to be reloaded. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the PHP, you shouldn't be using jQuery to be removing DIVs, it's a waste of resources and load time, even if it's just a few lines of code.

In your PHP template you should include the `#nfbadge` div in a conditional statement, something like:

```
if($notifications) {
     echo '<div id="nfbadge">';
     //notification stuff
     echo '</div>';
}
```

Then with your jQuery code you could do something like the following:

```
 var $nfbadge = $('#nfbadge');
 if($nfbadge) {$nfbadge.html(a)}
```

Answer (score 1):

.remove() takes the element out of the DOM as well as the content. This is why it doesn't come back unless you reload. Use .fadeOut() or .hide() instead

Comment: I tried to use .hide(), but for some reason it just won't work.

Comment: If onload it's empty and you call .hide(), it's hidden. Be sure to use .show() once content is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do something more like this:

```
var elm = $('#nfbadge'),
      T = setInterval(getCodes, 8000);

function getCodes() {
    $.get('/codes/php/nf.php', function(a) {
        elm.html(a);
        if (elm.is(':empty') && elm.is(':visible')) {
            elm.hide();
        }else{
            elm.show();
        }
   });
}
```

Will need some more work on your part, but should get you on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make the div hidden?

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/

Comment: please don't say hidden. That gives perhaps the thought to set the visibility. Better sey to set the display to none.

Comment: @SvenBieder: I think hidden is a good usage as in `$().hide()`